# Add a forked wallet to Wallect Connect

Tags: walletconnect

How can I add a forked metamask and white label it to use as Sentinece wallet with window.sentience to wallet connect sdk? I need to add this wallet to Gitcoin PAssport application.I tried set up of Gitcoin Passport on local system but facing database connection error.

Comment: Did you try contacting WallectConnect developers? I think you can register your wallet with them, and it will be available.